# Доступ к non-visible классу :)

Tags: java, рефлексия

Ниже представлен код, выполнение которого ругается на то, что я вызываю `.newInstance()` для класса, который в данном пакете не виден. Я там смоделировал то, чего хочется: типа `.setVilible("public")`.
Вопрос: Как избежать эксэпшэна?

В одном пакете:

```
package a;

import b.Creator;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        B b = Creator.next(B.class);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}

class B {

}
```

В другом пакете:

```
package b;

public class Creator {
    public static <T> T next (Class<T> clazz){
        try {
            clazz.setVisible("public");  // вымышленная строка
            clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().setAccessible(true);
            return clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

*Замечание*: не нужно выворачивать условия вопроса, предлагать объявить класс `B` как `public` в отдельном файле и всё такое. Нужно конкретно в заданных условиях создать экземпляр класса `B` внутри метода класса `Creator`.

Comment: Вам просто нужно вызывать newInstance() на конструкторе, который вы сделали доступным через setAccessible, а не на clazz.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Оформите это как ответ пожалуйста. Это оказалось так наивно просто, ахах.